# Lex (flex): how to provide input and where's output?

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm extremely new to Flex and I'm stuck at this early point. I have a Lex file 20.l whose content is

```
%{
/* a Lex program that adds line numbers
   to lines of text, printing the new text
   to the standard output
*/
#include <stdio.h>
int lineno = 1;
%}
line .*\n
%%
{line} { printf("%5d %s", lineno++, yytext); }
%%
main()
{ yylex(); return 0; }
```

I copied the code from my textbook (it doesn't tell me how to deal with my question here). I have done

```
flex 20.l
```

and got file lex.yy.c. Then I compiled it with

```
gcc lex.yy.c -o ADD -lfl
```

and got the executable file ADD.

Now how can I use this ADD to add line numbers to other text files? For example, what commands should I use if the input file name is "try.c"? I tried "./ADD try.c" but it obviously didn't work. And how is the output represented?

Thank you. I know this is really a stupid question but it seems nobody is teaching how to do this online...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried "./ADD try.c"

```
./ADD < try.c
```

The output appears on stdout. If you want different file handling you can write your own main().

Answer (score 2):

To enable the ./ADD try.c i.e. without using redirection 
you can use replace your main with following code in user-code section:

```
void main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc>0)
        yyin =fopen(argv[0], "r");
    else
        yyin = stdin;

    yylex();
}
```

You can enhance with input-argument options parsing for better input and output control.